# Grep latest file string

Tags: linux, grep, aix

**System: AIX 7.1**

Let's say I have a folder with files like these:

[image]

The files I need always have this prefix **sapemea_postatus.log.xxxxxxxx**, and inside of them we always have a number (collection number), like this:

[image]

And I always have questions like

> Hey, which collection number is the last one we have?

So I always have to open the FTP, navigate to the folder, filter the column to show the newest ones in the top, look for the latest **sapemea_postatus.log** file, download it and check with notepad++.

So my question is: Is there a way to make  grep command where I can filter for those kind of files, get the most recent one, and show this collection number? Thanks!

Comment: ls -tr > FILES; cat \`tail -1 FILES\` | grep ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

latest_collection=0

regex="Collection:[ ]*([0-9]+)"

for log in sapemea_postatus.log.*; do

    [[ $(cat $log) =~ $regex ]]
    collection="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

    if [[ $collection > $latest_collection ]]; then
        latest_collection=$collection
        latest_log=$log
    fi
done

echo "Latest log: $latest_log (number $latest_collection)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if I can create a file in the AIX server (if they let me) and try this!

Comment: If the serve won't let you create files then you can actually run the script as a one-liner since indentation has no significance in Bash. Just start `bash` if it's not the default shell of the system and then do `latest_collection=0; regex="Collection:[ ]*([0-9]+)"; for log in sapemea_postatus.log.*; do [[ $(cat $log) =~ $regex ]]; collection="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; if [[ $collection > $latest_collection ]]; then latest_collection=$collection; latest_log=$log; fi; done; echo "Latest log: $latest_log (number $latest_collection)"`

Comment: I wrote bash and hit enter, and pasted all the lines there ... how to execute it now? sorry, I'm really a beginner in aix

Comment: You hit enter again. Run this long line as if it were a command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought the Enter would just add an line, because it added a line and nothing happened, but this is because the search was taking some time to proccess...I hit enter and waited like 10 seconds and it showed the output, thanks!!!!